# ¿Se puede tener XAMPP y Tomcat EE instalados al mismo tiempo?

Tags: java, netbeans, tomcat, xampp

Tengo windows 10, XAMPP, Java y Netbeans instalado en mi PC. Estoy intentando crear un sitio Web para comercio electrónico siguiendo el tutorial "oficial"  del sitio de Netbearns.org:

```
https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/entity-session.html
```

Ese tutorial usa Glass Fish, pero yo he logrado llegar hasta el punto de crear las SessionBeans para las EntityClasses usando XAMPP que como saben trae Tomcat.

Pero hasta ahí llegué, porque al intentar crear las SessionBeans me dice que "Cannot be generated for Java EE 6 sources without server with complete  Java EE 6 Web Profile support (at least EJB Lite support)."

Investigo un poco y veo que necesito Tomcat EE.

**Mi pregunta específica:** ¿puedo instalar Tomcat EE junto a XAMPP y esperar que mi compu no presente conflictos?

Comment: Necesitas cualquier servidor de aplicaciones completo. Tomcat es solo *web profile*. Conflictos solo tendras si ejecutas ambos al mismo tiempo y ocupen los mismos puertos

Answer (score 1):

No debería entrar en conflictos porque el Apache del xampp por defecto se ejecuta en el puerto 80 y el Tomcat EE por lo general se ejecuta en el puerto 8080, sin embargo puedes cambiar el puerto del apache modificando el archivo `httpd.conf` que está en `C:/xampp/apache/conf/`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y para cambiar el puerto del tomcat EE en netbeans abre la vista de Servers, selecciona Apache Tomcat:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por contestar. Ya tengo instalado apache tomee webprofile 1.7.4 y al parecer no me causa conflicto cuando corre XAMPP. Pero al momento de intentar crear las Session Beans, me sigue con el mensaje de "Cannot be generated for Java EE 6 sources without server with complete  Java EE 6 Web Profile support (at least EJB Lite support)." ¿Esa versión de TomEE no soporta Java EE 6 Web Profile?

Comment: Para deployar EJBs necesitas OpenEJB chequea estos links: 
http://openejb.apache.org/apache-tomee.html
http://tomee.apache.org/application-deployment-solutions.html

Answer (score 0):

Cambia los puertos de apache que por defecto tiene el 80 o la ip 127.0.0.1 para que tomcat se ejecute con xampp o independiente.

Comment: Gracias, qué puerto debo poner para apache?

Comment: Hola, pues puedes ponerle el puerto 8080